# Why show different color in prototype presentation view in Figma?

Tags: prototype, figma

Why show different color in prototype presentation view in Figma, while in frame looks good and looks good also when export in png, jpg, PDF. But on prototype presentation look dark color?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand the question. Can you please reword it so that we can understand your problem?

Also, please provide a link to a sample of the Figma File that demonstrates the problem.